# Trying to get property 'rute_asal' of non-object on Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i just get error "Trying to get property 'rute_asal' of non-object". before i ask this queston, i tried so many things but not worked (i tried the similiar question by others too).

so, this my my code

Controller

```
 $biaya_pengantaran = BiayaPengantaran::latest()->get();
    $biaya_pelayaran = BiayaPelayaran::latest()->get();

    $detail_transaksi =  DetailTransaksiPengiriman::where('noinvoice', $noinvoice)->get();

    return view('pengiriman.create', compact('biaya_pengantaran', 'biaya_pelayaran', 'detail_transaksi'));
```

View:

```
      @foreach ($detail_transaksi as $item)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <small>Nama Penerima: {{ $item->nama_penerima }}</small><br>
                                    <small>Nama Penerima: {{ $item->telepon_penerima }}</small><br>
                                    <small>Nama Penerima: {{ $item->alamat_penerima }}</small>
                                    <br>
                                    <small>Rute Pengantaran:
                                        {{ $item->biaya_pengantaran->rute_asal }} -
                                        {{ $item->biaya_pengantaran->rute_tujuan }}

                                    </small><br>
                                    <br>
                                    <small>Merk/Tipe: {{ $item->merk_type }}</small><br>
                                    <small>Warna: {{ $item->warna }}</small><br>
                                    <small>No. Polisi: {{ $item->no_polisi }}</small>
                                    <br>
                                    <small>Biaya Pengantaran
                                        {{ number_format($item->biaya_pengantaran) }}</small><br>

                                    <small>Biaya Koordinasi {{ number_format($item->biaya_koordinasi) }}</small>
                                </td>
                                <td><b>{{ number_format($item->total_biaya_per_unit) }}</b></td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

Model:

```
 public function biaya_pengantaran()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(BiayaPengantaran::class);
}
```

Comment: Guessing it's in a foreach (would need to see some more code in view) but if `$item` is an instance of `biaya_pengantaran` then it would be `$item->rute_asal`. Can you share some more code in view?

Comment: @geertjanknapen yes, i already uptade it on my question

Comment: So does `DetailTransaksiPengiriman` have many `biaya_pengantaran` or does it belong to one? What happens when you do `@dd($item)` within the foreach?

Comment: @geertjanknapen nah, detailtransaksipengiriman belongsto biaya_pengantaran, because in detailtransaksipengiriman table, biaya_pengantaran_id having realtionship with id (primary key on biaya_pengantaran). so, biaya_pengantaran has many detailtransaksipengiriman and detailtransaksipengiriman belongs to biaya_pengiriman. sorry for my bad english

Comment: What do you get with `dd(DetailTransaksiPengiriman::first()->biaya_pengantaran)` - an object of class `BiayaPengantaran` or null?